# What's the best way to format an unreadable JSON file extracted through web-scraping using Beautiful Soup in Python to readable format?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

i web scraping using beautiful soup to get json data and print it to json file and its unreadable here look :

```
{"props":{"pageProps":{"profile":{"user_id":"588e3c6fdd927a7cfad7beed","username":"5OC","outfit":[{"item_id":"body-flesh","name":"","rarity":"","active_palette":3,"parts":[],"colors":{"dependent_colors":[],"palettes":[]}}
```

format it to this (i used formatter from chrome to convert it) here :

```
{
  "props": {
    "pageProps": {
      "profile": {
        "user_id": "588e3c6fdd927a7cfad7beed",
        "username": "5OC"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how can i convert it to readable data to extract a specific data from it and print it using python

Comment: Try `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` where `data` is your already parsed Json string. (note the `indent=` parameter)

Comment: When dump, pass `indent` argument